# Reading document array to a map from mongodb scala driver 2.4.2

Tags: mongodb, scala

I just switched from casbah to mongodb scala driver 2.4.2, everythig is a bit different here[asynchronous programming] and all i am looking here is to read the array from the mongodb document and convert this array to a map.

can anyone please help me the few missing steps.

Example document:

```
{
 "_id":"ESB0500_CROSSREF_TEST",
 "country_code":"WW",
 "instance_id":"1",
 "values": 
 {"1":"A","2":"B","3":"C","4":"D","5":"E","6":"F","7":"G","8":"H","9":"I","10":"J","11":"K","12":"L","13":"M","14":"N","15":"O","16":"P","17":"Q","18":"R","19":"S","20":"T","21":"U","22":"V","23":"W","24":"X","25":"Y","26":"Z"}
}
```

here i am looking to convert values array into map where key would be numbers and values would be alphabets like key 1 and value A

my query so far

```
val result = collection_obj.find(
      and(
        equal("_id",id),
        equal("country_code",country_code),
        equal("instance_id",instance_id)
      )
    ).projection(
      fields(
        include("values"),
        excludeId()
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is just transform your special array to a kind of a map maybe this can help you.

```
val array = Array("1", "A", "2", "B", "3", "C")

array.grouped(2).map { couple =>
  couple(0).toInt -> couple(1)
}.toMap
```